# How can I get JAWS to read the aria-describedby attribute of a fieldset?

Tags: wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I'm a developer working on making an application more accessible, and am very new to JAWS.

Everything I've read about `aria-describedby` has led me to believe that adding it to a `fieldset` with the ID of the element containing the description will cause the contents of the identified element to be read by the screenreader (in my case, JAWS) when users access the fieldset (See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute))

But when I test it, this doesn't happen. I've checked that the ID is correct.

Am I misunderstanding how `aria-describedby` works? Is there a setting I need to enable in JAWS to properly read aria attributes?

Answer (score 6):

This may be helpful: Practical Support: [aria-label, aria-labelledby and aria-describedby](https://w3c.github.io/using-aria/#label-support)

In the case you describe you can achieve the same outcome as you want by using `aria-labelledby` with multiple `id` refs, i.e. JAWS announces the legend and instruction text when the `fieldset` is navigated to.

```
<fieldset  aria-labelledby="legend-03 instruction">
        <legend id="legend-03">
            Which version of HTML do you use?
        </legend>
        <p id="instruction"> some important text</p>
        <input name="html" id="html43" value="html4" type="radio">
        <label for="html43">HTML4</label>
        <br>
        <input name="html" id="html53" value="html5" type="radio">
        <label for="html53">HTML5</label>
    </fieldset>
```

https://codepen.io/stevef/pen/PQMaxr